# Obtaining class name and property names from generic class

Tags: scala, reflection

Consider the following code:

```
trait GeneralTrait[T] {
   def getClassName() = ???
   def params() = ???
}

case class SomeClass(id: Long, name: String)

class ConcreteClass extends GeneralTrait[SomeClass]
```

Is it possible to make `getClassName()` return a String `'SomeClass'` and to make `params()` return a list `['id', 'name']` ?

Comment: How is your question actually related to the title?

Comment: Sorry, initially I was planning to ask help in obtaining TypeTag. I've changed the title.

Comment: Well your previous title suggests you already know the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well... I am not sure about what you are actually trying to do.

But, you can achieve most of this like following,

```
trait GeneralTrait { self =>
  def getClassName() = self.getClass.getSimpleName

  def params() = self.getClass.getConstructors.apply(0).getParameters
}

case class SomeClass(id: Long, name: String) extends GeneralTrait

val sc = SomeClass(5, "some")

sc.getClassName()
//res0: String = SomeClass

sc.params()
//res1: Array[java.lang.reflect.Parameter] = Array(final A$A55$A$A55 $outer, final long id, final java.lang.String name)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would advise you to always use scala reflection instead of java reflection. Names of classes and methods tend to get garbled a bit during compilation. Java doesn't know scala so it will always give you the garbled names.

If you want information about type parameters you will have to use scala reflection anyway.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag, typeOf}

trait GeneralTrait[T] {
   def getClassName()(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]) = typeOf[T].typeSymbol.name.toString
   def params()(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]) = typeOf[T].typeSymbol.asClass.primaryConstructor.asMethod.paramLists.flatten.map(_.name.toString)
}

case class SomeClass(id: Long, name: String)

class ConcreteClass extends GeneralTrait[SomeClass]

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.


scala> val c = new ConcreteClass
c: ConcreteClass = ConcreteClass@64d776b6

scala> c.getClassName
res0: String = SomeClass

scala> c.params
res1: List[String] = List(id, name)
```