# Obtaining the full info about fields of the case class in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection

Consider the following class and method:

```
case class User(id: Long, name: String) {
  private var foo = "Foo" // shouldn't be printed
  val bar = "bar" // also shouldn't be printed
}
case class Message(id: Long, userId: Long, text: String)

def printInfo[E](o: E)(implicit tt: TypeTag[E]) = {

}
```

I want to make this method print the name, type and value for each of the field for any case class, i.e.

```
printInfo(User(1, "usr1")) // prints something like "(id, Long, 1), (name, String)"
printInfo(Message(1, 1, "Hello World")) // prints "(id, Long, 1), (userId, Long, 1), (text, String, "Hello World")"
```

Adding some custom annotations for fields is also considerable.

Comment: What's goal? What have you already tried?

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189259/obtaining-class-name-and-property-names-from-generic-class).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could do this by inspecting the members listed by the type tag and reflecting using its mirror:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

def printInfo[A](a: A)(implicit tt: TypeTag[A], ct: ClassTag[A]): String = {
  val members = tt.tpe.members.collect {
    case m if m.isMethod && m.asMethod.isCaseAccessor => m.asMethod
  }

  members.map { member =>
    val memberValue = tt.mirror.reflect(a).reflectMethod(member)()
    s"(${ member.name }, ${ member.returnType }, $memberValue)"
  }.mkString(", ")
}
```

Which would work like this:

```
scala> case class User(id: Long, name: String) {
     |   private var foo = "Foo" // shouldn't be printed
     |   val bar = "bar" // also shouldn't be printed
     | }
defined class User

scala> case class Message(id: Long, userId: Long, text: String)
defined class Message

scala> printInfo(User(1, "usr1"))
res0: String = (name, String, usr1), (id, scala.Long, 1)

scala> printInfo(Message(1, 1, "Hello World"))
res1: String = (text, String, Hello World), (userId, scala.Long, 1), (id, scala.Long, 1)
```

(If you wanted `Long` instead of `scala.Long` it wouldn't be too hard to drop the prefix from the type you get from `member.returnType`, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.)

It's also not too hard to do this without any runtime reflection using Shapeless:

```
import shapeless.{ ::, HList, HNil, LabelledGeneric, Typeable, Witness }
import shapeless.labelled.FieldType

trait PrettyPrintable[A] {
  def apply(a: A): List[(String, String, String)]
}

object PrettyPrintable {
  implicit val hnilPrettyPrintable: PrettyPrintable[HNil] =
    new PrettyPrintable[HNil] {
      def apply(a: HNil): List[(String, String, String)] = Nil
    }

  implicit def hconsPrettyPrintable[K <: Symbol, H, T <: HList](implicit
    kw: Witness.Aux[K],
    ht: Typeable[H],
    tp: PrettyPrintable[T]
  ): PrettyPrintable[FieldType[K, H] :: T] =
    new PrettyPrintable[FieldType[K, H] :: T] {
      def apply(a: FieldType[K, H] :: T): List[(String, String, String)] =
        (kw.value.name, ht.describe, a.head.toString) :: tp(a.tail)
    }

  implicit def genPrettyPrintable[A, R <: HList](implicit
    ag: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, R],
    rp: PrettyPrintable[R]
  ): PrettyPrintable[A] = new PrettyPrintable[A] {
    def apply(a: A): List[(String, String, String)] = rp(ag.to(a))
  }

  def printInfo[A](a: A)(implicit pp: PrettyPrintable[A]) = pp(a).map {
    case (memberName, memberType, memberValue) =>
      s"($memberName, $memberType, $memberValue)"
  }.mkString(", ")
}
```

And then:

```
scala> PrettyPrintable.printInfo(User(1, "usr1"))
res2: String = (id, Long, 1), (name, String, usr1)

scala> PrettyPrintable.printInfo(Message(1, 1, "Hello World"))
res3: String = (id, Long, 1), (userId, Long, 1), (text, String, Hello World)
```

Among other things this gives you the fields in declaration order, which I think should be possible with the type tag approach, but I avoid that API as often as I can, so off the top of my head I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, `case class`es (which are an implementation of [`Product`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Product.html)) are now provided with a [productElementNames](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Product.html#productElementNames:Iterator[String]) method which returns an iterator over their field's names.

Combined with [productIterator](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Product.html#productIterator:Iterator[Any]):

```
// val user = User(1, "user")
(user.productElementNames zip user.productIterator)
  .map { case (field, value) => (field, value.getClass.getSimpleName, value) }
  .toList
// List[(String, String, Any)] = List((id,Long,1), (name,String,user))
```

This:

- extracts field names (`Iterator(id, name)`) using `productElementNames`
- extracts field values (`Iterator(1, user)`) using `productIterator`
- `zip`s field names with field values
- extracts the class name of values